# I am working on android so that I am coding to the edit text. After the code the text is just like something blinded in it

Tags: android

[image]

As in my attachment the text is just overriding on borders.
How to get free space in edit text like below one?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use a single line inside ever edit text

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

Will solve your problem.

**edittext_states.xml**(Make this drawable resource file in your drawable folder and set this in your editText Background).

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"
        /> <!-- focused -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

**set as background of edit:**

```
android:background="@drawable/edittext_states"
```

Comment: tq. one more problem i need to display the edit text in black color when it is not selected. And when it is selected it need to be highlighted with the other color. can it be possible for me. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Sure, give me few minutes I'll help you

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

it will help you

Comment: one more problem i need to display the edit text in black color when it is not selected. And when it is selected it need to be highlighted with the other color. can it be possible for me. Please help me out with this.

Comment: @ tejaswi  simply you use

Comment: @ tejaswi  simply you use                                                              <EditText
         android:hint="Your text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColorHint="#666666"
        android:textColor="#FFCE3838"/>